# Create drilldown fusion chart on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, fusioncharts

You will get results on the fusioncharts website if you search up what I asked, but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

I am querying data from a MySQL database, and putting this data into a fusion chart to display on my webpage. I want there to be 2 graphs on the same page, and when you click on one of the datapoints on the parent graph, the child graph will display the "drilled down" graph. How can I do this? As of right now I can press on the parent graph and it will open the child graph on a new webpage. This is the code for the home page with the parent graph. The file is named "dept.php".

```
<?php

/*Include the `fusioncharts.php` file that contains functions
        to embed the charts.
*/
  include("includes/fusioncharts.php");

 // Establish a connection to the database. Variables defined before
 $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

 // Render an error message, to avoid abrupt failure, if the database connection parameters are incorrect
 if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
      exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
 }

?>

<html>
   <head>
        <title>FusionCharts XT - Column 2D Chart - Data from a database</title>
          <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

        <!--  Include the `fusioncharts.js` file. This file is needed to render the chart. Ensure that the path to this JS file is correct. Otherwise, it may lead to JavaScript errors. -->

      <script src="fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <?php

        // Form the SQL query that returns the top 10 most populous countries
        $strQuery = "SELECT Department, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Scrap GROUP BY Department ORDER BY Department";

        // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
        $result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($result) {
                // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
                $arrData = array(
                "chart" => array(
                    "caption" => "Sample Chart",
                    "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
                    "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                    "borderAlpha"=> "20",
                    "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                    "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                    "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                    "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                    "showValues"=> "0",
                    "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                    "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
                )
                );

                $arrData["data"] = array();

        // Push the data into the array

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                "label" => $row["Department"],
                "value" => $row["Quantity"],
                "link" => "deptDrillDown.php?Department=".$row["Department"]
                )
                );
                }

                /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

                $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

                /*Create an object for the column chart. Initialize this object using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. The constructor is used to initialize
                 the chart type, chart id, width, height, the div id of the chart container, the data format, and the data source. */

                $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

                // Render the chart
                $columnChart->render();

                // Close the database connection
                $dbhandle->close();

        }

        ?>
        <div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And then here is the other page that contains the child graph. The file is named "deptDrillDown.php".

```
<?php

 /* Include the `includes/fusioncharts.php` file that contains functions to embed the charts.*/

   include("includes/fusioncharts.php");

   // Establish a connection to the database. Variables defined earlier
   $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

  /*Render an error message, to avoid abrupt failure, if the database connection parameters are incorrect */
   if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
        exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
   }
?>
<html>
   <head>
        <title>FusionCharts XT - Column 2D Chart</title>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

          <!--  Include the `fusioncharts.js` file. This file is needed to render the chart. Ensure that the path to this JS file is correct. Otherwise, it may lead to JavaScript errors. -->

        <script src="fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <?php

        // Get the country code from the GET parameter
        $countryCode = $_GET["Department"];

        // Form the SQL query that returns the top 10 most populous cities in the selected country
        $cityQuery = "SELECT ScrapDate, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Scrap WHERE Department = ? GROUP BY ScrapDate ORDER BY ScrapDate";

        // Prepare the query statement
        $cityPrepStmt = $dbhandle->prepare($cityQuery);

        // If there is an error in the statement, exit with an error message
        if($cityPrepStmt === false) {
                exit("Error while preparing the query to fetch data from City Table. ".$dbhandle->error);
        }

        // Bind the parameters to the query prepared
        $cityPrepStmt->bind_param("s", $countryCode);

        // Execute the query
        $cityPrepStmt->execute();

        // Get the results from the query executed
        $cityResult = $cityPrepStmt->get_result();

        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($cityResult) {

                /* Form the SQL query that will return the country name based on the country code. The result of the above query contains only the country code.
                The country name is needed to be rendered as a caption for the chart that shows the 10 most populous cities */

                $countryNameQuery = "SELECT ScrapDate FROM Scrap WHERE Department = ?";

                // Prepare the query statement
                $countryPrepStmt = $dbhandle->prepare($countryNameQuery);

                // If there is an error in the statement, exit with an error message
                if($countryPrepStmt === false) {
                exit("Error while preparing the query to fetch data from Country Table. ".$dbhandle->error);
                }

                // Bind the parameters to the query prepared
                $countryPrepStmt->bind_param("s", $countryCode);

                // Execute the query
                $countryPrepStmt->execute();

                // Bind the country name to the variable `$countryName`
                $countryPrepStmt->bind_result($countryName);

                // Fetch the result from prepared statement
                $countryPrepStmt->fetch();
                // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
                $arrData = array(
                "chart" => array(
                    "caption" => "Top 10 Most Populous Cities in ".$countryName,
                    "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
                    "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                    "borderAlpha"=> "20",
                    "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                    "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                    "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                    "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                    "showValues"=> "0",
                    "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                    "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
                )
                );

                $arrData["data"] = array();

        // Push the data into the array
                while($row = $cityResult->fetch_array()) {
                array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                "label" => $row["ScrapDate"],
                "value" => $row["Quantity"]
                )
                );
                }

           /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

                $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

          /*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is `FusionCharts("type of chart",
                 "unique chart id", "width of chart", "height of chart", "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`.*/

                $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

                // Render the chart
                $columnChart->render();

                // Close the database connection
                $dbhandle->close();
        }
        ?>

        <a href="dept.php">Back</a>
        <div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- `n` number of charts can be rendered in a single page using FusionCharts.
- Store their chart references, e.g. in an associative array.
- Use the [`dataplotClick`](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events.html#event-dataplotClick) event to capture the event being generated by clicking on a data.
- Inside the callback, use the [`setJSONData`](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#setJSONData) to update the child chart, one wanna update.

A dummy code for this would be:

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var chart1 = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'msstackedcolumn2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container1',
    width: '550',
    height: '350',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
       // enter the json data here
    },
    "events": {
        "dataplotClick": function(eventObj, dataObj) {
             /* so every time a dataClickEvent is being triggered from the data plot,
                a new json `json2` is fetched from a sql query and
                chart2 is updated with it.*/
             chart2.setJSONData(json2);
        }
    }
} 
}).render();    
});
```

Couple of days back I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyanGhatak/k34zayjw/embedded/result%2Cjs%2Chtml%2Ccss/), hope this becomes useful here too. Instead of doing a SQL query, here we have a generalised data, every time a click is made, it internally makes a function call, and creates a data dynamically out of it. Lot of function calls for making it entirely dynamic might make the code look complex. But the basic philosophy I shared in the dummy code avobe is the same here.

The snippet version for the code for a quick reference.Better to run the result in full page to check whats exactly happening.

```js
function getData() {

  var arr = [{
    seriesname: "Book A",
    data: [{
      "label": "Paper",
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "label": "Promotion",
      "value": 150
    }, {
      "label": "Transportation",
      "value": 175
    }, {
      "label": "Royality",
      "value": 200
    }, {
      "label": "Printing",
      "value": 250
    }, {
      "label": "Binding",
      "value": 275
    }]
  }, {
    seriesname: "Book B",
    data: [{
      "label": "Paper",
      "value": 130
    }, {
      "label": "Promotion",
      "value": 110
    }, {
      "label": "Transportation",
      "value": 155
    }, {
      "label": "Royality",
      "value": 250
    }, {
      "label": "Printing",
      "value": 210
    }, {
      "label": "Binding",
      "value": 215
    }]
  }, {
    seriesname: "Book C",
    data: [{
      "label": "Paper",
      "value": 70
    }, {
      "label": "Promotion",
      "value": 180
    }, {
      "label": "Transportation",
      "value": 125
    }, {
      "label": "Royality",
      "value": 150
    }, {
      "label": "Printing",
      "value": 290
    }, {
      "label": "Binding",
      "value": 245
    }]
  }, {
    seriesname: "Book D",
    data: [{
      "label": "Paper",
      "value": 150
    }, {
      "label": "Promotion",
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "label": "Transportation",
      "value": 105
    }, {
      "label": "Royality",
      "value": 125
    }, {
      "label": "Printing",
      "value": 278
    }, {
      "label": "Binding",
      "value": 235
    }]
  }, {
    seriesname: "Book E",
    data: [{
      "label": "Paper",
      "value": 60
    }, {
      "label": "Promotion",
      "value": 250
    }, {
      "label": "Transportation",
      "value": 115
    }, {
      "label": "Royality",
      "value": 189
    }, {
      "label": "Printing",
      "value": 190
    }, {
      "label": "Binding",
      "value": 285
    }]
  }, {
    seriesname: "Book F",
    data: [{
      "label": "Paper",
      "value": 190
    }, {
      "label": "Promotion",
      "value": 200
    }, {
      "label": "Transportation",
      "value": 160
    }, {
      "label": "Royality",
      "value": 148
    }, {
      "label": "Printing",
      "value": 178
    }, {
      "label": "Binding",
      "value": 295
    }]
  }];

  return arr;
}

function getValues(componentName) {
  var i,
    j,
    arr = getData(),
    valueArr = [],
    len1;
  for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0, len1 = arr[i].data.length; j < len1; j += 1) {
      if (arr[i].data[j].label === componentName) {
        valueArr.push({
          value: arr[i].data[j].value
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return [{
    seriesname: componentName,
    data: valueArr
  }];
}

function getProducts(componentName) {
  var arr = getData(),
    productArr = [];
  for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr[i].data.length; j += 1) {
      if (arr[i].data[j].label === componentName) {
        productArr.push({
          "label": arr[i].seriesname,
          "value": arr[i].data[j].value
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return productArr;
}

function getComponents(label, value) {
  var arr = getData(),
    sum,
    i,
    j,
    len,
    len1,
    obj =
    componentArr = [];
  if (label === undefined) {
    label = true;
  }
  if (value === undefined) {
    value = true;
  }
  for (i = 0, len = arr[0].data.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    sum = 0;
    obj = {};
    for (j = 0, len1 = arr.length; j < len1; j += 1) {
      sum += arr[j].data[i].value;
    }
    if (label) {
      obj.label = arr[0].data[i].label;
    }
    if (value) {
      obj.value = sum;
    }
    componentArr.push(obj);
  }
  return componentArr;
}

function getSeriesNames() {
  var arr = getData(),
    seriesName = [];
  for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    seriesName.push({
      "label": arr[i].seriesname
    });
  }
  return seriesName;
}

function getMode() {
  var e = document.getElementById("interaction");
  return e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}

FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var lastClickedId = true;

  var pieChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie2d',
    renderAt: 'pieContainer',
    width: '600',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Expenditures Incurred in Publishing a Book",
        "subCaption": "Component-wise BreakUp",
        "enableMultiSlicing": "0",
        "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
        "showvalues": "1",
        "showpercentvalues": "1",
        "showborder": "0",
        "showplotborder": "0",
        "showlegend": "1",
        "legendborder": "0",
        "legendposition": "bottom",
        "enablesmartlabels": "1",
        "use3dlighting": "0",
        "showshadow": "0",
        "legendbgcolor": "#CCCCCC",
        "legendbgalpha": "20",
        "legendborderalpha": "0",
        "legendshadow": "0",
        "legendnumcolumns": "3",
        "palettecolors": "#f8bd19,#e44a00,#008ee4,#33bdda,#6baa01,#583e78"
      },
      "data": getComponents()
    },
    "events": {
      "dataplotClick": function(eventObj, dataObj) {
        if (getMode() === 'pie') {
          var json = stackedChart.getJSONData(),
            categoryLabel = dataObj.categoryLabel;
          json.chart.subCaption = "BreakUp of " + categoryLabel + " in different product";
          json.categories[0].category = getSeriesNames();
          json.dataset = getValues(dataObj.categoryLabel);
          stackedChart.setJSONData(json);
        }
      }
    }
  }).render();

  var stackedChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedBar2D',
    renderAt: 'barContainer',
    width: '600',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
        "outcnvbasefontcolor": "666666",
        "caption": "Expenditures Incurred in Publishing a Book",
        "subCaption": "Product-wise BreakUp",
        "xaxisname": "Expenditures Cost",
        "yaxisname": "Cost",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "showvalues": "0",
        "numvdivlines": "10",
        "showalternatevgridcolor": "1",
        "alternatevgridcolor": "e1f5ff",
        "divlinecolor": "e1f5ff",
        "vdivlinecolor": "e1f5ff",
        "basefontcolor": "666666",
        "tooltipbgcolor": "F3F3F3",
        "tooltipbordercolor": "666666",
        "canvasbordercolor": "666666",
        "canvasborderthickness": "1",
        "showplotborder": "1",
        "plotfillalpha": "80",
        "showborder": "0",
        "legendbgcolor": "#CCCCCC",
        "legendbgalpha": "20",
        "legendborderalpha": "0",
        "legendshadow": "0",
        "legendnumcolumns": "3"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": getComponents(true, false)
      }],
      "dataset": getData()
    },
    "events": {
      "dataplotClick": function(eventObj, dataObj) {
        if (getMode() === 'stackedBar') {
          var JSON = pieChart.getJSONData(),
            categoryLabel = dataObj.categoryLabel;
          JSON.chart.subCaption = "BreakUp of " + categoryLabel + " in different product";
          JSON.data = getProducts(categoryLabel);
          pieChart.setJSONData(JSON);
          pieChart.slicePlotItem(dataObj.datasetIndex);
        }
      }
    }
  }).render();

  function resetFN() {
    var json = pieChart.getJSONData();
    json.chart.subCaption = "Component-wise BreakUp";
    json.data = getComponents();
    pieChart.setJSONData(json);

    json = stackedChart.getJSONData();
    json.chart.subCaption = "Product-wise BreakUp";
    json.categories[0].category = getComponents(true, false);
    json.dataset = getData();
    stackedChart.setJSONData(json);
  }

  document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', resetFN);
  document.getElementById('interaction').addEventListener('change', resetFN);

});
```

```css
h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.intro {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff280;
  padding: 15px
}

em {
  font-style: italic
}

#interactionWrapper {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #0b77bc;
  background-color: #0d83ce;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px 0 0 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.centerAlign {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  <h4>Expenditures incurred while publishing books</h4>
  <p><em>A company has 6 books to publish for this quater. The stacked chart shows component prices stacked as per different books. While the pie chart, shows the cumilative component price.</em></p>
  <p>
    <em>There are two interaction modes - namely "Interact in stacked chart" and "Interact in pie chart".On clicking in any plot on stacked chart, it shows the book-wise distribution of that component in the pie chart. Whereas on clicking the pie chart, for a component being clicked, it shows the book-wise distribution in the bar chart</em>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="interactionWrapper">
  <span>Interaction Mode:</span>
  <span>
            <select id="interaction">
              <option value="stackedBar">Interact in stacked bar</option>
              <option value="pie">Interact in the pie chart</option>
            </select>
        </span>
</div>
<div class="centerAlign">
  <span id="barContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</span>
  <span id="pieContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</span>
</div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Jsfiddle gives me 404.. anyway can you provide the working link for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Use the link attribute to define a simple link for a data plot. It belongs to the data object and accepts the URL of the page that will open when the user clicks on a data plot. Specify it for each clickable data plot.

```
    {
    "chart": {
       ...
    },
    "data": [{
        "label": "Apple",
        "value": "810000",
        "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"
    }, {
        "label": "Cranberry",
        "value": "620000",
        "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry"
    }, {
        "label": "Grapes",
        "value": "350000",
        "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grape"
    }]
}
```

To know more about it please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/drill-down#simple-links